# Which Onsen Ryokan do Tim Ferris and Kevin Rose speak about?

Tags: japan, ryokans

The transcript reads:

> Tim Ferriss: So, different uses, to be used sparingly or all the time, in case of K. Rose. And we are at Adaia, as the name of the place. And if you hear any waterfall-like sounds in the background, that is because we have a natural onsen bringing water into the rooms where there are wooden tubs that are effectively indoor/outdoor. There’s an open wall so, you look out into a forest/hillside, and the steam pours out into the great outdoors. It is winter so, there’s tons of fog and mist and so, on; it’s just a magical place.

> Kevin Rose: It’s absolutely beautiful. One of the reasons I chose this place to stay is one, I had never stayed in a ryokan, like a traditional Japanese house before and I always wanted to do that.

( from https://tim.blog/2018/06/22/the-tim-ferriss-show-transcripts-the-random-show-with-kevin-rose-224-the-random-show-drinking-urine-exploring-japan-and-figuring-out-life/ )

I don't think the description can fit many places because I don't think there are many Ryokan that all tick the following boxes:

- Natural Onsen bringing water into the room
- Half indoor/outdoor tubs
- Open wall to forest/hillside

I think the spelling `Adaia` is not correct. I found a couple with the spelling `Ohtaya` or `Otaya` (e.g. https://www.booking.com/hotel/jp/ryokan-otaya.de.html ) but neither seemed to be a good fit, because it isn't near a forest/hillside and also does not seem to have private in-room Onsens.

Comment: I've voted to close because I don't think the question contains enough detail for this to be anything other than a wild goose chase. You're asking for a specific onsen to be identified based on a description that sounds like a generic onsen and a placename which you assume is wrong anyway. You've already found some candidates and it isn't clear why you've discarded them or what it would take to convince you somebody else's answer is satisfactory.

Comment: Let me edit and add a bit more context. :)

Comment: It does not say the tubs are half indoor/outdoor. It says they are *in the rooms*, which have an open wall, and the steam pours out into the great outdoors. So the tubs are *effectively* indoor/outdoor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found [the page on Tim's site for the podcast](https://tim.blog/2017/02/26/the-random-show-drinking-urine-exploring-japan-and-figuring-out-life/) (rather than the transcript) and at the bottom it has a number of bullets that include:

> - We’re staying at the [Araya Totoan](http://www.araya-totoan.com/en/)

Which feels pretty definitive to me.

Answer (score 7):

Listening to the actual clip, the speaker sounds like he has a good understanding of the pronunciation of Japanese words, so I don't think he mispronounced or misread, but that the person doing the transcript couldn't hear the word.

I believe he said "Araya" (the "ra" sound in Japanese can sometimes sound like a "da" sound to people). This could possibly be referring to be [Araya Totoan](http://www.araya-totoan.com/en/index.html). Though this is situated just [outside of Kanazawa](https://www.google.com/maps/place/%E3%81%82%E3%82%89%E3%82%84%E6%BB%94%E3%80%85%E5%BA%B5/@36.2717998,136.3002434,12.54z/data=!4m8!3m7!1s0x5ff8f71cd98c1915:0xd41d5a9a8e6b8a06!5m2!4m1!1i2!8m2!3d36.288724!4d136.362022) it may be close enough for people so just include it in Kanazawa (I think it's a bit of a strech). You can check out the site to see that they have open-walled private baths facing a forest.

In the end, however, if you really want to know, it'd be best just ask Tim himself.

Comment: Nice find! The "Wakana" rooms here.seem to fit the bill perfectly, including the "open wall": http://www.araya-totoan.com/en/room/03.html

Answer (score 6):

The blog mentions Kanazawa (Ishikawa-ken), so I'm <s>reasonably certain</s> actually incorrect about them staying at **[Tadaya](https://tadaya.net/eng/)** (多田屋), a rather famous ryokan in [Wakura Onsen](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Wakura_Onsen) on the nearby Noto Peninsula, which does indeed feature private outdoor baths:

[image]

Update: I was wrong and Kate's answer is correct.

For what it's worth, you don't need to head all the way to Wakura to experience this.  The following search for onsen hotels where at least some of the guest rooms have private outdoor baths (露天付き客室) returns **452** (!) results all across Japan: https://www.yukoyuko.net/special/t00024

Comment: That's a great list. Is it safe assuming they will accept foreigners or do you have to check?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany If you book online they're not going to refuse entry, but if there's no English website, they're unlikely to be set up for visitors who speak no Japanese.

Comment: @lambshaanxy what an amazing answer, thx a ton! :)

Comment: Wakura is, however, one of the onsen resorts where you can enjoy the onsen while having an extraordinary ocean view. But well, there aren't so few of them either. I suppose one could try Izu (Ito or Shimoda), or Ise-Shima, both of which should have more options for tourists not speaking Japanese...